# Mathematica not evaluating any trigonometric integrals

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

When I input any integral, say sin[x] or ln[x], all I get back is the input. And from what I understand that usually means that mathematica can't evaluate the integral...What am i missing here?
I'm new to stackoverflow so I can't post screenshots.

Comment: Mathematica likes to capitalize its commands.  Try `Sin[x]` and `Ln[x]`.  Also try looking through the help for Mathematica.  It will have some examples.

Comment: Jesus...That's it? Capitalisation?.... Damn I feel stupid for not thinking of that :D

Comment: This may save you time, too: Don't write Sin^2[x] in Mathematica, use Sin[x]^2.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation:

- [Sin[x] manual](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sin.html)
- [Log[x] manual](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log.html)

Note also that by default **Log** function is of base **e**, therefore it is your **Ln**.

In addition, if you have further questions mathematica/wolfram has it's own subsite where you should ask related questions https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

---

As of version 9 you can query wolfram alpha directly and it can even try to interpret human language (and fix syntax mistakes like this). To query wolfram alpha start line with <kbd>=</kbd>.